# ASP.Net <%# %> and <%= %> rules?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2005

Can someone explain to me the rules around what can and cannot be evaluated/inserted into markup using the <%# %> and <%= %> tags in asp.net?

When I first discovered I could inject code-behind variables into mark-up using <%= I thought 'great'. Then I discovered that if such tags are present you can then not add to the controls collection of the page (that's a whole different question!). But <%# tags are ok.

Is there a way I can inject a code-behind variable or function evaluation into the page using <%# ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<%#` inline tag is used for data binding, so if you want to use a code-behind variable inside it, you will have to bind the page or control the variable resides in:

```
Page.DataBind();
```

You can include this statement in the `Page_Load` or `Page_PreRender` event.

See [this article](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx) for more information about the use of inline tags in ASP.Net, and [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301536.aspx) for more about server-side databinding.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Worked a treat! I'll read the articles when I've a bit more free time!

Answer (score 2):

`<%%>` are code blocks. You can put any server side code in them. This is a shortcut for `<script runat="server"></script>`.

`<%=%>` is for outputting strings. This is a shortcut for `<script runat="server">Response.Write()</script>`.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx) for more detail about `<%%>` and `<%=%>`.

`<%#%>` are used for [data binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx).

See the [index page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h.aspx) for asp.net Page syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Useful info but I'm afraid Prutswonder solved my issue :)